# Economics book which study video game economies

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics

I saw this very interesting [Ted Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-I6Qn56QWI&pp=ygUWdGVkIHRhbGsgdGYyIGVjb25vbWNpcw%3D%3D) which discusses the Economics of a popular game called Tf2. This piqued my curiosity, but I couldn't find much more of this content on youtube. Searching for the term "Video Game economics" leads results more about the economics of buisnesses which sell video games rather than internal economics of video games.

---

[Related](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/14609/understanding-inflation-in-a-video-game)

Comment: Maybe check out this one: https://www.amazon.com/-/de/dp/0262535068/

Answer (score 2):

Check Out the book Virtual Economies: Design and Analysis by Edward Castronova and Vili Lehdonvirta. And for video game economics research papers see Isaac Knowles' google scholar page and his interview at "market power" Youtube channel